# Including a subquery within the FROM statement in a SQL query in JPA

Tags: sql, database, jpa, jpql, criteria-api

I have a Spring Boot app. In it, I have a SQL query that requires creating a subquery, inner joining the results of that subquery with another table, and then selecting from the results of that inner join. But apparently JPA doesn't let you use subqueries within FROM clause (I assume neither using JPQL nor using Criteria API). Is there any way around this?

I have thought about storing the results of the subquery in a temporary entity (ideally not creating a table persistable to the DB), and then selecting from the data stored within those entities. But I'm not sure how to do this using Spring. I want something even more "temporary" than creating a cache since the results of the subquery go away from memory after the query is executed.

Here is a SQL query similar to what I want to do:

```
SELECT g1.name, g1.publisher, g1.price, g1.released_at
FROM games AS g1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT released_at, MAX(price) as price
  FROM games
  GROUP BY released_at
) AS g2
ON g2.released_at = g1.released_at AND g2.price = g1.price;
```

I'm expecting the results from the SQL query described here:
http://bernardoamc.github.io/sql/2015/05/04/group-by-non-aggregate-columns/

Comment: What is the real problem you want to solve using this query? Can you describe a little bit more? I guess that you want to find the game which has max price for each release date. Is this correct? If yes, please take a look at my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this query:

```
Select g from games g where not exists (
   Select g1 from games g1 
    where g1.released_at = g.released_at and g1.price >= g.price
)
```